# OpenPose Library - setup issue

Tags: python, openpose

**I could not configure the openpose project correctly with python. Can someone mention the steps to setup the project of https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose .** (I have to get the facial key points and body key points)

Comment: Have you looked at this tutorial? https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-human-pose-estimation-using-opencv-cpp-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed openpose for Ubuntu 16.04. Here are the steps I followed:

1. I have installed Nvidia drivers and cuda-10.0 for RTX 2080 Ti GPU with the help of      this [link](https://medium.com/@avinchintha/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-and-cuda-10-0-for-rtx-2080-ti-gpu-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-ce32e4edf1c0)
2. I have copied files to corresponding folders like mentioned in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767269/how-can-i-install-cudnn-on-ubuntu-16-04)
3. I have installed caffe by following this [link](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/caffe-installation-uk.html)
4. I followed the steps for Ubuntu in [openpose github](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md#installation)

Since I had already installed Cuda and Cudnn, I skipped these steps.